# Here are/is my rhinoceros and horse

Tags: subject-verb-agreement

Which is correct in this example?

1. Here are my rhinoceros and horse
2. Here is my rhinoceros and horse

Comment: What a weird example you have chosen.  Do many people in your country own rhinos?

Answer (score 1):

What follows the verb determines whether the verb is singular or plural.

In this particular case, what follows is plural (a rhino and a horse, that is, two animals).

Comment: That isn't always the case, if the 2 things form a unit or natural group then *is* may work, but it is the case here.